# How can I create a language like PHP and how does it work?

Tags: php, compiler-construction, language-design

I want to know how to create a language like PHP. How does the server know how to translate a PHP file? How does it work? I want to do this for educational purposes. A simple language with basic features like echo, etc.

Comment: Not a full answer, but you can download PHP's source code from php.net. It's written in C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366998/good-resources-on-programming-language-design gives a few hints on how to go about designing a programming language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In basics, when webserver get's request to process php file it translating this request to php processor, it could be a module (like php.so in apache) or service (like php-cgi). Service or module compiles php script to machine code, executes it and gives the server the result of his job. You can download php source code from http://php.net. Source code include parser, thanslator, compiler and other components needed to execute php script as machine code

Comment: How does the webserver automatically know to process this request.

Comment: Throu config file. For example in apache config
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

Comment: This is wrong. The version of PHP at php.net compiles to bytecode for execution by the Zend VM. PHP is usually either interpreted or compiled to intermediate code. Compilation to machine code is possible but not the rule.

Answer (score 4):

Divide your task in at-least two top level parts:

1. PHP as just another programming language - you need a lexical analyzer, parser and interpreter.
2. Libraries and modules for web servers likt Apache/TomCat to inteface with PHP.

Comment: 3) a cgi-bin(or alternatives) module or an apache module

Answer (score 2):

This is a very big question. And not one which can really be answered here, but a few pointers to get you started...

PHP exposes some of its inner workings - if you have a look at:

```
<?php

$srctokens=token_get_all(file_get_contents(__FILE__));
print "<pre>\n";
foreach ($srctokens as $tok) {
   print token_name($tok[0]) . ' -&gt; ' . $tok[1]; 
}
?>
```

You'll see that it splits the code up into 'words' and assigns meta-data to each one (is it a function name, a variable, an operator...).

It then builds this into a tree structure, e.g. an 'if' statement might have three child nodes - an expression to evaluate (which itself would have child nodes), some code to evaluate if the expression is true, and some code to evaluate if the expression is false.

Typically it will use a set of built-in functions to read in data from the outside and to push data to the outside world.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) or google are usually good starting points for finding out about stuff you don't know.

Its worth noting that because its an interpreted language, its simple to create executable code from PHP datastructures using eval() or create_function() (or just using temporary files). Indeed you could even implement a structured rewriting system such that the original data looks nothing like PHP code. e.g. [lolcode](http://lolcode.com/implementations/implementations)

But you need to be very careful that you don't expose this mechanism to someone who might abuse it.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You could also write it in PHP, like [BobX](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/We-Use-BobX.aspx).  Please note, BobX is actually an example of what **NOT** to do.